# Inserting a common header and Signal headers for selectable number of signals, then pushing the real-time signals to a CSV file in Twincat / Beckhoff

Tags: twincat

I am here requesting for your support and I hope I'll get a solution for this.

I want to create a CSV file with attached format(image). Where there will be a common header and Signal headers for selectable number of signals and then the real-time signals values.

As far I have managed to create a new file and only able to push the actual data to 1st row only. Not able to create the required format. Any inputs will be very helpful.

It would be great if someone could share some examples or so.

Thanks in advance...https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or0LO.jpg

Comment: Did you see [this on InfoSys?](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclibutilities/html/tcplclibutilities_csv_sample.htm&id=). Or maybe [repo](https://github.com/benhar-dev/tc3-csv-read-write) will help.

Comment: Yes, after going through Infosys, I have managed to create a CSV and to push only the actual data as shown in image. Also, I have to write these data to Buffer memory in a fixed interval and the buffer data to CSV in every 1sec or 1 min. Can anyone help please?